# Polars DataFrame filter data in a period of time (start and end time)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-polars

Is there a way to filter data in a period of time (i.e., `start time` and `end time`) using `polars`?

```
import pandas as pd
import polars as pl

dr = pd.date_range(start='2020-01-01', end='2021-01-01', freq="30min") 
df = pd.DataFrame({"timestamp": dr})
pf = pl.from_pandas(df)
```

The best try I've got was:

```
pf.filter((pl.col("timestamp").dt.hour()>=9) & (pl.col("timestamp").dt.minute()>=30))
```

It only gave me everything after `9:30`; and if I append another `filter` after that:

```
pf.filter((pl.col("timestamp").dt.hour()>=9) & (pl.col("timestamp").dt.minute()>=30)).filter((pl.col("timestamp").dt.hour()<16))
```

This however does not give me the slice that falls right on `16:00`.

`polars` API do not seem to specifically deal with the `time` part of time series (only `date` part); Is there a better workaround here using `polars`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question!

Firstly, we can create this kind of DataFrame in Polars:

```py
from datetime import datetime, time
import polars as pl

start = datetime(2020,1,1)
stop = datetime(2021,1,1)
df = pl.DataFrame({'timestamp':pl.date_range(start=start, end=stop, interval="30m",eager=True)})
```

To work on the time components of a datetime we cast the `timestamp` column to the `pl.Time` dtype.

To filter on a range of times we then pass the upper and lower boundaries of time to `in_between`.

In this example I've printed the original `timestamp` column, the `timestamp` column cast to `pl.Time` and the filter condition.

```py
(
df
.select(
    [
        pl.col("timestamp"),
        pl.col("timestamp").cast(pl.Time).alias('time_component'), 
        (pl.col("timestamp").cast(pl.Time).is_between(
            time(9,30),time(16)
        ).alias("timestamp_in_range")
        )
    ]
)
)
```

What you are after is:

```py
(
df
.filter(
        pl.col("timestamp").cast(pl.Time).is_between(
            time(9,30),time(16)
            )
        )
)
```

See the API docs for the syntax on controlling behaviour at the boundaries:
https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.Expr.is_between.html#polars.Expr.is_between

Comment: The casting line of code is exactly what I was looking for thanks!

Comment: keyword `include_bounds` is now `closed` I think, and the default is 'both' which means both boundaries are included --> [docs](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.is_between.html).

Comment: Updated for Polars 0.18.9

Answer (score 2):

It is described in the polars book here: https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/howcani/timeseries/selecting_dates.html#filtering-by-a-date-range

It would look something like this:

```
start_date = "2022-03-22 00:00:00"
end_date = "2022-03-27 00:00:00"
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "dates": [
                  "2022-03-22 00:00:00",
                  "2022-03-23 00:00:00",
                  "2022-03-24 00:00:00",
                  "2022-03-25 00:00:00",
                  "2022-03-26 00:00:00",
                  "2022-03-27 00:00:00",
                  "2022-03-28 00:00:00",
                 ]
    }
)
df.with_column(pl.col("dates").is_between(start_date,end_date)).filter(pl.col("is_between") == True)


shape: (4, 2)
┌─────────────────────┬────────────┐
│ dates               ┆ is_between │
│ ---                 ┆ ---        │
│ str                 ┆ bool       │
╞═════════════════════╪════════════╡
│ 2022-03-23 00:00:00 ┆ true       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-03-24 00:00:00 ┆ true       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-03-25 00:00:00 ┆ true       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-03-26 00:00:00 ┆ true       │
└─────────────────────┴────────────┘
```

Comment: more succinctly: `df.filter(pl.col("dates").is_between(start_date, end_date))`